# Android selecting document from device but not able to get the file name with the extension type

Tags: java, android, file-upload

I want the user to be able to upload pdf and image file to server and after
selecting the file I want to display the name of the file and the type wether it's .pdf
or .png

But the file extension is not included in the file path

This is how I start the intent

```
   btnUploadDocument.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            chooseFile.setType("image/*|application/pdf");
            chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
            startActivityForResult(chooseFile, REQ_UPLOAD_DOCUMENT);
        });
```

and here's how I get the data returned

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == REQ_UPLOAD_DOCUMENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

        Uri path = data.getData();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = FTLBookingActivity.this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(path);
            byte[] pdfInBytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
            inputStream.read(pdfInBytes);
            String encodedPDF = Base64.encodeToString(pdfInBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Document Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I tried selecting an image and the path was having below value

```
content://media/external/images/media/599
```

Comment: Yes, and that no path but uri.toString() the content scheme  of the obtained uri. If you have any questions then put them in your post please.

Comment: @blackapps Okay then how can I get the file name and extension. I think it's obvious what my question is

Comment: Questions should be asked in the post. Not in comments.

Comment: @blackapps My desired result is written in the post and the title and the actual result is also in the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the file extension is not included in the file path

There is no "file path", as this is not a file.

> I want to display the name of the file and the type wether it's .pdf or .png

Use `DocumentFile.fromSingleFile()` to wrap your `Uri` in a `DocumentFile`. You can then [use `getName()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile?getName()) and [`getType()` on the `DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile?getType()) to get a display name and MIME type, respectively.